# Fcm Voice || video call notification with node js and flutter

Tags: node.js, flutter, firebase-cloud-messaging

What i'm searching for is a way to send a call notification using FCM like sending a long period notification with a ringstone, i heard that there is some packages for that but i don't know how to use it with node js.
if anyone knows an answer plzz share it with us.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should use flutter_callkit_incoming package it's really easy to use just read the documentation  https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_callkit_incoming

Comment: Your answer could be improved by providing an example of the solution and how it solves the problem. A link to the documentation will also improve the quality of your answer.